# How to group by a column with forloop and union all

Tags: php, mysql, foreach, group-by, union

Hi this is my query from this query i am getting 3 records i want only one record and i am trying to group by `studentid`

```
foreach ($gdFinaldata['gdskill'] as $skillId => $skillScore){

$filterQuery .= $union_all. "SELECT stu.student_pid

FROM tbl_students stu LEFT JOIN r_job_invitations jbi ON stu.student_email = jbi.email 

LEFT JOIN r_job_scores jsc  ON jsc.student_id = stu.student_pid 

WHERE job_id = ".$jobID."  AND skill_id = ".$skillId." AND gd_score >= ".$skillScore." ";

$union_all=" UNION ALL ";

} //for ends here
```

the recodrs will come like this:

```
SELECT stu.student_pid FROM tbl_students stu LEFT JOIN r_job_invitations jbi ON stu.student_email = jbi.email LEFT JOIN r_job_scores jsc ON jsc.student_id = stu.student_pid WHERE job_id = 88 AND skill_id = 3 AND gd_score >= 1   
UNION ALL
SELECT stu.student_pid FROM tbl_students stu LEFT JOIN r_job_invitations jbi ON stu.student_email = jbi.email LEFT JOIN r_job_scores jsc ON jsc.student_id = stu.student_pid WHERE job_id = 88  AND skill_id = 63 AND gd_score >= 2   
UNION ALL  
SELECT stu.student_pid FROM tbl_students stu LEFT JOIN r_job_invitations jbi ON stu.student_email = jbi.email LEFT JOIN r_job_scores jsc ON jsc.student_id = stu.student_pid WHERE job_id = 88  AND skill_id = 128 AND gd_score >= 3
```

After this i want to add group by how can i do that i tried like this:

```
$groupby = "GROUP BY student_id";
$filterStudents = $conn->query($filterQuery.$groupby);
```

> My issue is still returning 3 records i want to group by student

For Reference:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do this.

- Use `union` instead of `union all`, this will retain only unique entries

  ```
  select ...
  union
  select ...
  union
  select ...
  ```
- If you want to keep `union all` (why do you?), use parenthesis around your selects and append `group by` after it

  ```
  select student_pid
  ( select student_pid, student_id from ...
  union all
  select student_pid, student_id from ...
  union all
  select student_pid, student_id from ... ) as t
  group by student_id
  ```

  Your PHP would then look like

  ```php
  foreach (...) {
      $filterQuery .= $union_all. "SELECT stu.student_pid, jsc.student_id ..."
      // ...
  }

  $outerQuery = "select student_pid ("
  $groupby = ") as t GROUP BY student_id";
  $filterStudents = $conn->query($outerQuery . $filterQuery . $groupby);
  ```
- Instead of `group by`, you can also use `distinct`, e.g.

  ```
  select distinct student_pid
  ( select student_pid from ...
  union all
  select student_pid from ...
  union all
  select student_pid from ... ) as t
  ```
- Collect the result in an array and then use [`array_unique`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php)
  Although this is the least efficient, since it fetches all entries instead of the relevant parts.

Comment: Yes, your file query should be. SELECT * FROM ( select ...
union
select ...
union
select ... ) as grptable
group by grptable.student_pid

Comment: Something is missing trying to debug.. thanx for your help hope this works.

Comment: Maybe the additional column in the inner query ($filterQuery), see updated answer.